# How to set different width for INPUT and DIV elements with Scriptaculous Ajax.Autocompleter?

Tags: ajax, scriptaculous, autocomplete

I am working on autocompleter box based on [Scriptaculous Ajax.Autocompleter](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/ajax-autocompleter).

It works in general, but I need to have list of choices wider (see [image](http://twitpic.com/1j1ry9) -- green line -- 320px) then input box (see [image](http://twitpic.com/1j1ry9) -- red line -- 155px).

My first try was to **set various `width` with CSS classes** (like above), but it didn't work -- list of choices became as wide as input box.

According to Firebug `width` defined by my CSS class was overwritten by `width` set by `element.style` CSS class, which seems to be defined by `Ajax.Autocompleter`.

My second try was to set `width` for list of choices after creating `Ajax.Autocompleter`

```
$("isearch_choices").setStyle({width: "320px"});
```

but it didn't work too :(.

No more ideas :(.

**How to set different width for list of choices for Scriptaculous Ajax.Autocompleter?**

Below there is complete example of code:

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.0.3/prototype.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.8.2/scriptaculous.js"></script>

        <style>
            input.iSearchInput {
                width: 155px; 
                height: 26px; 
                margin-top: 7px; 
                line-height: 20px;
            }

            div.iSearchChoices {
                position:absolute;
                background-color:white;
                border:1px solid #888;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                width: 320px;
            }      
            div.iSearchChoices ul {
                list-style-type:none;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }

            div.iSearchChoices ul li.selected { background-color: #ffb;}

            div.iSearchChoices ul li {
                list-style-type:none;
                display:block;
                margin:0;
                padding:2px;
                height:32px;
                cursor:pointer;
                border-bottom: 1px dotted #929292;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <input type="text" maxlength="255" class="input iSearchInput" name="isearch_value" id="isearch" value="Search" onfocus="this.select()">
        <br>
        <div id='isearch_choices' class='iSearchChoices'></div>

    </script>


</body>

<script>
    function iSearchGetSelectedId(text, li) {
        console.log([text, li.innerHTML].join("\n"));
        document.location.href = li.getAttribute("url");
    }

    document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
        try {
            new Ajax.Autocompleter("isearch", "isearch_choices", "/url", {
                paramName: "phrase", 
                minChars: 1,
                afterUpdateElement : iSearchGetSelectedId
            });
        }
        catch (ex) {
            alert(ex);
        }

        $("isearch_choices").setStyle({width: "320px"});



    });

</script>

</html>
```

And link to image with its [result](http://twitpic.com/1j1ry9).

Answer (score 1):

The width is reset in the autocompletion list automatically by the `Base.Autocompleter` implementation. The `Base.Autocompleter` will set the list to be the same width as the search input field. There are a couple of ways to go around this:

### 1. Patch Autocompleter.Base by yourself

You can patch the `Autocompleter.Base` script by yourself as described by [this post](http://jameshalberg.com/2007/12/13/prototype-autocompleter-width/). For script.aculo.us version 1.8.1 in controls.js at line 68 you have the following:

```
Position.clone(element, update, {
  setHeight: false, 
  offsetTop: element.offsetHeight
});
```

Add a `setWidth: false` into that options object like this:

```
Position.clone(element, update, {
  setWidth: false,
  setHeight: false, 
  offsetTop: element.offsetHeight
});
```

### 2. Extend very your Autocompleter

The example below is for extending the `Ajax.Autocompleter`. The idea is to replace the `onShow` function that the base class will call in order to show the autocompleter and resize it with `Position.clone()`.

```
/**
 * Extension of Ajax.Autocompleter that disables width reset.
 * @class
 */
var MyAutocompleter = Class.create(Ajax.Autocompleter, {

    /**
     * @constructor
     * @param $super reference to the base class (provided by prototype.js)
     * @param id_for_search the id for the search input element
     * @param id_for_list the id for autocompletion list element
     * @param url the ajax url to be used
     */
    initialize: function($super, id_for_search, id_for_list, url) {

        $super(id_for_search, id_for_list, url, {
            onShow: function(element, update) {
                if(!update.style.position || update.style.position=='absolute') {
                    update.style.position = 'absolute';
                    Position.clone(element, update, {
                        setHeight: false, 
                        setWidth: false,
                        offsetTop: element.offsetHeight
                    });
                }
                Effect.Appear(update,{duration:0.15});
            }
        });

    }

});
```

And you create it as usual with `new` just as with the other Autocompleter classes.

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    new MyAutocompleter('search', 'autoList', 'url/for/ajaxcall');
});
```

The benefit of the latter is that you can update the script.aculo.us version without repatching the files, and you can continue to overload and extend the Autocompleter to your liking (given you know how the base class behaves).

Comment: You can also add an "onShow" callback in the options parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be fixed. I modified CSS stylesheets and seems (visually) to work:

1. Removed border from `DIV` element and moved it `UL` element.
2. Add `width` for `UL` element.

Here are my changes:

```
        div.iSearchChoices {
            position:absolute;
            background-color:white;
            /* border:1px solid #888; */
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            /* width: 320px; */
        }      
        div.iSearchChoices ul {
            list-style-type:none;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            /* moved from div.iSearchChoices class */
            border:1px solid #888;
            width: 320px;
        }
```