# How to extend the scriptaculous autocompleter?

Tags: autocomplete, scriptaculous

The autocompleter in [script.aculo.us](http://script.aculo.us/) expects that the server response is a `<ul>` list. Is there some way for me to extend or replace this behaviour so it can take server response that is an XML or JSON document instead?

Is there also a way to extend the autocompleter's renderer so I can add a footer to the autocompletion list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can extend the behaviour of script.aculo.us's autocompleter. You do this by overriding the `onComplete` method with code that handles the json data and creates the `<ul>`-list for you. This list should then be sent to `updateChoices`.

Say you will retrieve the following JSON response when you search for "U":

```
[
  "Unicorn",
  "University"
]
```

An example of an extension of Ajax.Autocompleter that can handle the response above:

```
var MyCompleter = Class.create(Ajax.Autocompleter, {

    initialize: function($super, id_search, id_list, url, options) {
        $super(id_search, id_list, url, options);
    },

    onComplete: function(response) {
        var text = response.responseText;
        if (text.isJSON()) {
            this.handleJSON(text.evalJSON());
        }
        // else do nothing
    },

    handleJSON: function(json) {
        var htmlStr = '<ul>';
        json.each(function(item) {
            htmlStr += '<li>';
            htmlStr += item;
            htmlStr += '</li>';
        });
        htmlStr += '</ul>';
        this.updateChoices(htmlStr);
    }

});
```

There is also an example on how to [replace autocompleter's width reset behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724344/how-to-set-different-width-for-input-and-div-elements-with-scriptaculous-ajax-aut/4994528#4994528).